# How do I park secure.primary.com on top of the multisite ID:1 domain: www.primary.com (primary multisite domain)

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

We have a multisite setup, the primary domain needs to have www.primary.net, and secure.primary.net mapped in wordpress so the primary site's content loads on both. The problem we are facing is secure.primary.com doesn't work. secure.primary.net always ends up at: http://www.primary.net/wp-signup.php?new=secure.primary.net

The headers returned from the server are as follows:

Status: HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily Date: Tue, 16 Oct 2012 19:55:53 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://www.primary.net/wp-signup.php?new=secure.primary.net
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Basically I just need this to work, even if it means ripping into the core Wordpress files and making changes.  I've tried various domain mapping plugins and such and nothing works correctly.  One of the problems is that they don't allow mapping on the primary network domain.  Any suggestions on what I can edit in WordPress or a starting point would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [WordPress MU Domain Mapping<sup>*Plugin*</sup>](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/), and edit the `wp_domain_mapping` database table.

Insert a new row for `blog_id` #1 manually, for example:

```
 +------+-----------+----------------------+----------+
 |  id  |  blog_id  |  domain              |  active  |
 +------+-----------+----------------------+----------+
 |  5   |  1        |  secure.primary.com  |  1       |
 +------+-----------+----------------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a table where WordPress stores the Path->Blog ID references. IF you add another record that points your second path to Blog ID 1 along with the regular entry, you might solve your problem.

I don't have an MS setup right now to look into the Database structure.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I don't think this would work. The table that maps domain names to blogs (`wp_blogs`) has a primary key on the `blog_id` field -- meaning that any attempt to another domain that maps to that blog will result in an `ERROR ... Duplicate entry`